# How does npm (or yarn) handle dependencies of my dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm

I've been using npm and yarn for a while, and still have some questions on dependency graph.

If i install two packages, A and B of certain version, and if B has A as dependency, but of a different version from my direct dependency, does both versions get installed?

For example, my package.json has package A of version 1.0.0 as dependency, but package B has dependencty A of version 0.9. I wonder if both versions are installed, and if so, where

If not so, how is this situation handled?

Comment: http://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html

Comment: Both are installed if their versions of the dependency are incompatible. If they are compatible only a single version satisfying both constraints is installed.

Comment: Thanks. Does yarn do it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Each dependency you install have a `packages.json` and a *node_modules* folder in it. The inner node modules will contain it's dependencies.

Here's a screenshot of *body_parser*

[image]